# Trying to uninstall and fresh install Ruby on Ubuntu: do I still have Ruby installed?

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu

I'm coming from Windows to Linux (Ubuntu) so I'm new to the CLI. I had issues trying to install Rails so I figured a fresh install would help. I'm following "[Installing Ruby the Correct Way](http://cbednarski.com/articles/installing-ruby)."

I thought I had uninstalled Ruby, but after installing 2.1.4 it still shows some Ruby folders. Have I completely uninstalled Ruby?

```
Downloading ruby-2.1.4.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/bf9952cdeb3a0c6a5a27745c9b4c0e5e264e92b669b2b08efb363f5156549204
Installing ruby-2.1.4...
Installed ruby-2.1.4 to /home/richard/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4
richard@richard-ThinkPad-T400:~$ rbenv global 2.1.4
richard@richard-ThinkPad-T400:~$ ruby -v
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
* ruby
* ruby1.8
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
richard@richard-ThinkPad-T400:~$ sudo rbenv global 2.1.4
richard@richard-ThinkPad-T400:~$ ruby -v
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
* ruby
* ruby1.8
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Are the "the following packages" on my local system? or are they online?

*EDIT*
I've been getting this error when I try to install RVM (and some other applications):

`GPG signature verification failed for '/home/richard/.rvm/archives/rvm-1.26.0.tgz' - 'https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/releases/download/1.26.0/1.26.0.tar.gz.asc'!
try downloading the signatures:`

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3
```

they can be compared with:

```
https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc
https://keybase.io/mpapis
```

Does this have anything to do with it? I wouldn't really think so but I'm a noob.

Comment: as you have install ruby in /home/richard/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4, so you need add path of `/home/richard/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4` to PATH environmental variable

Comment: No, the "following packages" are suggested by apt-get, which knows where commands can be found because it loads a database containing all file names from each package source. Be assured, no ruby any more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't `sudo rbenv` anything or you will summon Cthulhu. Use `rbenv` by itself.

Also, don't randomly follow guides on the internet until you're more familiar with your OS; They go stale, or start out wrong, or don't accurately apply to what you're doing. Instead, go to [the source](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) and follow the directions there.

To find out what is installed on your machine, use `locate` to quickly find Ruby instances. Something like:

```
locate /bin/ruby | grep -v .rbenv
```

should narrow down whether multiple Rubies are installed outside the ~/.rbenv directory.

Traditionally, you'll find a normally installed system-wide Ruby in /usr/bin/ruby. A user installed one from source will probably be in /usr/local/bin/ruby unless you specifically said otherwise, probably with a `PREFIX=` directive.

rbenv will default to installing Ruby in the ~/.rbenv hierarchy since it acts like a sandbox manager and will put all Rubies it installs underneath that directory. [RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/install), a similar application, will use ~/.rvm, and in both cases, the purpose is to keep them where the user's permissions are sufficient to install and update gems without requiring the use of `sudo`. For general use, avoid `sudo` unless you understand what you're about to do, as it can turn a computer into an under-desk heater in seconds.

---

The shell uses the PATH variable to figure out where to look for executable commands. It sounds like your PATH isn't set correctly. If you followed the directions on the rbenv site, they say how to enable rbenv by modifying your ~/.bash_profile script. Doing that, then closing and reopening your shell should bring rbenv to life.

Comment: Ok thanks! Like you mentioned, I did find a Ruby in /usr/bin/ruby. But when I try ruby -v it doesn't find anything. Do I need to install while in the 'top level directory'? I am now assuming my default directory when I open the CLI isn't the 'top level directory'.

Comment: Well, and people think the GOTO statement is evil. The inflationary use of sudo (I won't blame anyone...) really made people forget it's power. After doing a `su - root` you simply knew that Bad Things Might Happen (tm). I hated using sudo as default for system administration from Warthog on, iirc.

Comment: Read the additional answer.

Comment: @Richard: The ruby might well be a symbolic link. Check the output of `ls -la /usr/bin/ruby`.

Comment: Heh, `GOTO` is useful when you have too much CPU time on your hands and need to burn some off.

Comment: This is what I've tried:
richard@richard-ThinkPad-T400:~$ ls -la /usr/bin/ruby
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
richard@richard-ThinkPad-T400:~$ locate /bin/ruby | grep -v .rbenv
/usr/local/bin/ruby
richard@richard-ThinkPad-T400:~$ ls -la /usr/bin/ruby
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
richard@richard-ThinkPad-T400:~$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/ruby
ls: cannot access /usr/local/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
richard@richard-ThinkPad-T400:~$

Comment: PROGRESS! I have rbevn working (so far) and ruby 2.1.4 working. but when I try to install rails, I get the following error: 
richard@richard-ThinkPad-T400:~$ sudo gem install rails
[sudo] password for richard: 
sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/gem: No such file or directory
richard@richard-ThinkPad-T400:~$ which gem
/home/richard/.rbenv/shims/gem
richard@richard-ThinkPad-T400:~$

Comment: Thanks for all of the help! I think I got it. I at least figured out if ruby was installed! Now I'm just figuring out my gem PATH stuff. Thanks again.

Comment: You can't format comments beyond using simple formatting. Do *NOT* use `sudo gem install` with rbenv managed Rubies. `sudo` changes your effective user to root, and root's environment knows nothing about rbenv and its Rubies, so, instead of installing somewhere in ~/.rbenv, the gems will land wherever the default system Ruby (in /usr/bin/ruby usually) says to put them.

Answer (score 1):

Following that blog post, you are installing Ruby using a tool called rbenv, and if you only uninstalled one Ruby, that doesn't mean that all Rubies are uninstalled.

The message that you posted shows that it is a local install:  `Installed ruby-2.1.4 to /home/richard/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4` which is a copy of the 4th line of your message.

You can find out from whence your Ruby executable is being invoked by issuing at the command line:

```
which ruby
```

You will then know if the program is available and which it is.  Using `ruby -v` if it is there will tell you the version.

You have done some of these steps and are finding out that your system does not know how to get to the Ruby, if it is indeed installed.

Right now, it is effectively uninstalled, as it is unavailable to your environment.

Comment: Thanks vgoff, Is there a way to get rid of everything associated with ruby for a fresh start? (aside from re-installing Ubuntu hopefully)

Comment: Because rbenv is storing all related things in your ~/.rbenv file, it would be 'safe' to `rm -rf ~/.rbenv` and then remove any references to your `~/.bashrc` or whatever resource files your favorite shell uses.  From there, open a new terminal, and start again.